# How to avoid checking for empty value in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I'm trying to grasp how Haskell programs can avoid testing for "empty value". I am struggling to get rid of case expression in this program:

```
main =  do url:outputPath:[] <- getArgs
         let maybeUri = parseURI url
         case maybeUri of
              Just uri -> download uri outputPath
              Nothing -> return ()
```

My very rough understanding is that I should use monad transformer so that I can use single `mappend` on Maybe value within IO monad and 'do' syntax should be able to support it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `forM_` from `Data.Foldable`, which has the following type:

```
forM_ :: (Monad m, Foldable t) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
```

`Maybe` implements the `Foldable` class, behaving like a list with zero or one elements, so when you specialize the `t` in the above type signature to `Maybe` you get:

```
forM_ :: (Monad m) => Maybe a -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
```

You use it like this:

```
forM_ maybeUri $ \uri -> download uri outputPath
```

It will only run the action if the `Maybe` value turns out to be a `Just`.

Comment: Or if `downloadTo = flip download`, then just `forM_ maybeUri $ downloadTo outputPath` which reads a lot more nicely in my opinion.

Comment: @kqr Usually if I can eta-reduce the argument I switch to using `Data.Foldable.mapM_`: `mapM_ (downloadTo outputPath) maybeUri`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Data.Maybe.maybe` (it's also in the Prelude so no import needed):

```
main = do
  url:outputPath:[] <- getArgs
  let maybeUri = parseURI url
  maybe (return ()) (\uri -> download uri outputPath) maybeUri
  -- The above can also be written as:
  -- maybe (return ()) ((flip download) outputPath) maybeUri
```

`maybe` takes:

- a function to run in case of a `Nothing`: here, `(return ())`
- a function to run on the value inside a `Just`: here, `(\uri -> download uri outputPath)`
- the `Maybe` value: `maybeUri`

I show an alternative way to express the function on the `Just` value, using a partially-applied function.

I would argue for using `maybe` because it makes it explicit, without having to write out the case expression, that you're dealing with a `Maybe`.